# Spoof the src ip address when querying to DNS

Tags: python, shell, dns, dig

I am using python
I want to spoof srcip address when sending DNS query?

Python code is not neccessary? Even shell command do the purpose.

I tried dig but error comes.
eg

```
$dig -b 10.0.1.1 google.com
dig: isc_socket_bind: address not available
```

can anyone know how to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: is 10.0.1.1 the IP of your host?

Comment: no it is the spoofed address
Please correct me if i was wrong in command

Answer (score 3):

man dig says

> ```
>  -b address
> ```

```
     Set the source IP address of the query to address.  This
     must  be  a  valid  address on one of the host's network
     interfaces or 0.0.0.0 or ::. An  optional  port  may  be
     specified by appending: #<port>
```

so 10.0.0.1 (or whatever spoofed address you are using) should be a valid network ip in your local network.

Comment: Thanks i got it,
Is their is any way i can spoof the src addredd via shell command or some code